# Claims by Jehovah's witnesses from doctrine?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

I have heard these three claims at different times from Jehovah's witnesses said in the presence of other JWs. Are they based in JW doctrine?

1. Jehova created dinosaurs for the purpose of clearing forests for humans to plant crops and removed them when that task was done.
2. The "abomination that maketh desolate" (KJV) or "disgusting thing that is causing desolation" (NW) mentioned in Dan 11:31 is a prophecy identified with the United Nations in New York, with particular condemnation of the display in the UN of the "swords into plowshares" quotation from Isaiah 2:4.
3. The "breath of life" that Jehovah put into the nostrils of Adam in Gen 2:7 is what we call oxygen. It is essential for living things and impossible for humans to make; scuba divers and astronauts cannot survive without bringing oxygen with them.

Comment: Here is how I heard these claims.
1. Lecture by a visiting overseer to a JW meeting at Lambertseter School, Oslo, Norway. He addressed the subjects of Why were there dinosaurs? and Will we (JWs) have clothes in heaven?
2. Stated in a JW family and consistent with the answer below.
3. Stated personally to me by the head JW overseer in Norway. When I objected that it is easy to demonstrate that a mouse or a man can be supplied with breathable oxygen that is manufactured chemically, he pulled a disgruntled face and ran.

Answer (score 2):

```
Jehova created dinosaurs for the purpose of clearing forests for humans to 
plant crops and removed them when that task was done.
```

I can find no evidence this is has ever been official teaching of the Watchtower Society. It teaches a naive Young Earth philosophy, but does not claim that God created dinosaurs for the purpose of clearing forests for humans to plant crops.

```
The "abomination that maketh desolate" (KJV) or "disgusting thing that is 
causing desolation" (NW) mentioned in Dan 11:31 is a prophecy identified with 
the United Nations in New York, with particular condemnation of the display 
in the UN of the "swords into plowshares" quotation from Isaiah 2:4.
```

The Watchtower Society is ambivalent in regard to the United Nations. On the one hand, Jehovah's Witnesses believe that the United Nations will soon destroy all other religions, and then turn against Jehovah's Witnesses. On the other, the Society secretly joined the United Nations as a non-government organisation (NGO). Wikipedia states:

> Jehovah's Witnesses teach that the United Nations is the "image of the wild beast" referred to in Revelation 13:1-18 and the fulfillment of the "disgusting thing that causes desolation" from Matthew 24:15.[6][7] Jehovah's Witnesses believe that Jehovah will use the United Nations to destroy "false religion" as an institution, wherein all institutionalized religions except Jehovah's Witnesses will be destroyed. It is expected that the United Nations will then turn against Jehovah's Witnesses to destroy them, but Jehovah will intervene and destroy all political elements. They believe this act of divine intervention will be Armageddon, the final part of the Great Tribulation.[8][9]
>
> In practice, Jehovah's Witnesses "view the United Nations organization as they do other governmental bodies of the world," as "superior authorities" that "exist by God's permission," based on their interpretation of Romans 13:1, 2. They believe "this Scriptural position does not condone any form of disrespect toward governments or their officials," to which they are to "render due respect," and they "obey them as long as such obedience does not require that they sin against God.

The [Jwfacts](http://www.jwfacts.com/watchtower/united-nations-association.php) site says the Watchtower became an Associate NGO with the United Nations in 1992 and provides copies of what are purported to be official UN documents. Tami Dickerson, a Jehovah's Witness at the time, says in *[Jehovah's Witnesses and the United Nations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466387602)*, page 7, that as soon as she heard that the Watchtower had joined the United Nations, she began to investigate and eventually concluded that the report was true.

So, the second statement in the question is at least partly true, but the Watchtower Society seems to be backing away from its former total opposition to the United Nations.

```
The "breath of life" that Jehovah put into the nostrils of Adam in Gen 2:7 
is what we call oxygen.
```

The Watchtower Society teaches that humans do not have a soul in the traditional Christian sense. Therefore, according to Witnesses, the "breath of life" can not be ensoulment. [This Wikipedia reference page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Science/2011_July_9#Jehovah.27s_Witnesses_and_oxygen) shows that some Witnesses do teach that the  "breath of life" that Jehovah put into the nostrils of Adam in Gen 2:7 is what we call oxygen, whether or not this is official doctrine:

> The Jehovah's Witnesses doctrine expounded to me by a national overseer is that oxygen is *pneu* the breath of God which was imparted to living things at their creation.